# Thread won't stop in onPause

Tags: android, multithreading, handlers

I'm trying to stop my thread in my onPause() but the thread still runs and gets the notification that is sent when the thread expires. It seems I have everything set right... My notifcation works fine and comes up after the 8000 sleep.. but if the user leaves/onPause() before then the notification will still pop.

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
     private NotificationManager notificationManager;
     private Notification myNotification;
 Thread timer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expire);

        timer = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(8000);                    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                               myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.missedcall,
                                 "Exired",
                                 System.currentTimeMillis());
                               Context context = getApplicationContext();
                               String notificationTitle = "Time Expired";
                               String notificationText = "Try next time";
                               Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                               PendingIntent pendingIntent
                                 = PendingIntent.getActivity(CallScreen.this,
                                   0, myIntent,
                                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                               myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                               myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                               myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
                                  notificationTitle,
                                  notificationText,
                                  pendingIntent);
                               notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
                               finish();


                    }
                }
            };
            timer.start();

}


@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        timer.stop();
        finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**: Do you want the code in the `finally` statement to always execute? Because, as written, you're not going to be able to exit the thread without updating your notification.

If thats ok, just call `timer.interrupt()`, which will trigger your InterruptedException handler & then call your `finally` block - if you're averse to interrupting threads and **really feel attached** to your Thread you can always use  a latch to release it.

```
public class SomeDamnedActivity extends Activity {
    // ... misc junk ...
    private CountDownLatch mLatch;
    private Thread mThread;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        mThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mLatch.await(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Interrupted waiting for latch to release", e);
                } finally {
                    // Stuff goes here that you want to execute.
                }
            }
        };      
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // ...
        mLatch.countDown(); // This will release the latch "prematurely" calling your finally-statement.
    }
```

(FYI: An AsyncTask is probably a better idea or posting a `Runnable` to a View in your layout using `View#postDelayed(Runnable, long)` )

Comment: What I think I'm going to do and I tested that it work is move the notifcation up into the try under `sleep(8000);` then call `timer.interrupt()` in the `onPause()`... so that way if it runs 8 secs the notifcation will come up and the activity will `finish()` but if the user leaves or starts a new activity within the 8 secs... the thread will call `timer.interrupt()` in the `onPause()` and they won't see the expired notifcation.

That's essentially what I want. DO you see any problems doing it that way?

Answer (score -1):

Just out of curiosity, how do you know that onPause() is actually called?

Use Toast or Log to find out, that your app enters the onPause() state